# Sort HTML table which has children with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table, hierarchy

I have the following table structure. I want to sort this by drag and dropping. Please note that I want the root pages to have children pages. I have it working with list with hierarchy but this makes styling for legacy browsers impossible.

```
<table>
   <tr data-id="1">
       <td>Page name</td>
       <td>Other column</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="2">
       <td>Page name</td>
       <td>Other column</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="children" data-parent="2">
       <table>
            <tr data-id="3">
                <td>Page name</td>
                <td>Other column</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-id="4">
                <td>Page name</td>
                <td>Other column</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you written any JavaScript yet, or are you just asking for someone to do this for you?

Comment: You can't do that with a table I believe. You can if you render it in list ("li") elements.
With the jquery li you can start building it: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: SO what you have tried. show your effort.

Comment: I have done it with ("li") elements however when you do it that way you wont get table style css (columns that resize on content and fixed width columns in one row).